# How do I fix my MySQL server

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, localhost

I use a local Apache server for many things, but I never really had a use for MySql. I recently decided to keep a local copy of Wordpress, so I installed MySql.

I tried to install PHPMYADMIN, but every time I tried to log on I got a blank screen. I tried with good and bad credentials and even the CONFIG mode. I even did the same thing without using the install script. When I gave up on PHPMYADMIN, I just used the console to make the database, which worked fine. When I put in all the information for wordpress to automatically make the setup file, I also got a blank screen.

I never entered the information for wordpress manually because I created a php document that looked like the one below to test it (Thanks to W3 SCHOOLS http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_create.asp ) All information I do not want you to see has been replaced.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","USERNAME","PASSWORD");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

if (mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE test_databse",$con))
  {
  echo "Database created";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error creating database: " . mysql_error();
  }

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I got the following error message.

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): [2002] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not (trying to connect via tcp://localhost:3306) in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\test.php on line 2
Warning: mysql_connect(): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\test.php on line 2
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\test.php on line 2
```

I checked to make sure MySql was running as a service (which it was)

Comment: Can you connect to the mysql server from the command line ?

Comment: This might be better of @ superuser.com

Comment: @the in cases like this you don't have to flag for mod attention, just vote to close as belongs on super.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your my.cnf

This settings should be there:

```
[mysqld]
port            = 3306
# Local access only
bind-address           = 127.0.0.1
```

And please check your Windows Firewall - or Personal Firewall if there is one.

And a good package to start with apache, php and mysql on Windows can be found here: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

Comment: All I could find was my.ini, but it looked similar.
port = 3306 was already there and bind-adress = 127.0.0.1 didn't help

P.S. I tried XAMPP before and I didn't like it so I just downloaded everything seperately.

Comment: Did you check your firwall settings?

Answer (score 0):

Open notepad with administrative privileges by

> clicking Start > All Programs > Accessories
>
> Right click Notepad and select Run as administrator

In notepad open your hosts file, which should be located in `c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` or somewhere similar
You may need to change the file types from Text Documents (*.txt) to All Files (*.*) in the Open window in notepad Comment out the line

> 127.0.0.1             localhost